# Create element in another div element using classname

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create new elements in another pre-existing `<div>` element using js DOM. 
I'm able to do this if that `<div>` is called using `id` but I want to accomplish this by `class`

This is what I have so far

```
<html>

  <body>
      <button onclick="whiskey()">go</button>


       <div class="pagination-pagination-right">
       <!-- I want to spawn new Elements here !-->
       </div>

       <div class="controlElement">
       <p> This  is just a control Element</p>
       </div>


       <script type="text/javascript">

       function whiskey(){
       var input=document.createElement("input");
       input.type="text";a
       input.id="sad";



       var newdiv=document.createElement("div");
       newdiv.appendChild(input);

          /* this part  doesn't work */
       var maindiv=document.getElementsByClassName("pagination-pagination-right"); 
       maindiv.appendChild(newdiv);
       }

      </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is an array like collection of object, which does not have the `appendChild()` method. You need to get the first element form the list using an index based lookup then call the `appendChild()`

```js
function whiskey() {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  //ID of an element must be unique
  input.id = "sad";



  var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
  newdiv.appendChild(input);

  var maindiv = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination-pagination-right");
  maindiv[0].appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="whiskey()">go</button>


<div class="pagination-pagination-right">
  <!-- I want to spawn new Elements here !-->
</div>

<div class="controlElement">
  <p>This is just a control Element</p>
</div>
```

Comment: well..many thanks!! worked fine..Also Can you please tell me How to make a script to run only once...in a browsing session(until page is refreshed).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this by using jQuery

**HTML**

```
   <button>go</button>

   <div class="pagination-pagination-right">
   <!-- I want to spawn new Elements here !-->
   </div>

   <div class="controlElement">
   <p> This  is just a control Element</p>
   </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('<div>A</div>').appendTo('.pagination-pagination-right');
    });
});
```

You can replace `$('<div>A</div>')` part with whatever element you want to append in your `<div>`

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9uvn20a4/)